# A regular expression to detect/delete both of the most external "(double quote)

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to detect/delete both of the most external "(double quote).
For example, I'd like to remove the most external ones like this.

```
"111"222"333"222"111"
=>> 
111"222"333"222"111
```

Could you give me a regular expression for this, plz??

Answer (score 1):

If your language/tool supports capture groups, then one straightforward approach would be to match on this pattern:

```
"(.*)"
```

and then replace with `$1` or `\\1`, which is the first capture group.

This would only match if the string has double quotes on both sides.  If you expect other behavior, then the pattern would have to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Regex-1

```
(^("\1)|("\1)$)
```

This regex matches both extreme double quotes of a string as a whole. Use any function to delete.

Regex-2

```
((\B")|("\B))
```

This regex matches both extreme double quotes of a word. Works even if you have multiple words in a string.

Thank you

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works. If it is not working please let me know.